# Angular7 SCRIPT445: Object doesn't support this action IE sortable.js

Tags: angular, internet-explorer

I am usig sortable js with angular7 and while clicking on the sortable icon I get this error in IE:

SCRIPT445: Object doesn't support this action

without any more information except: File: polyfills.js, Line: 8103, Column: 25

Tried to investigate or search solution but without any results may someone help?

Removing sortable.js doesn't throw this error. Also it worked in A5

Comment: what's sortable.js you are using? Are you using [this plugin](https://github.com/SortableJS/Sortable)? Can you share related reference about the sortable.js, so that we could test it on our side.

Comment: Yes I am using this plugin
"sortablejs": "^1.8.0-rc1", 
"angular-sortablejs": "^2.6.0",

Comment: @ adi86, I try to create a sample using these plugins, it seems that everything works well on my IE 11 browser (v11.1.17134.0). Please check your IE browser version, and refer to the sample on my reply. If still not solve the problem, can you post the Enough code to reproduce the problem as in [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Update to latest Sortable 1.8.1 :)

Answer (score 1):

You could refer to the following steps to use sortablejs and angular-sortablejs.

1. install the sortable package and import the reference.

   Install [sortablejs](https://github.com/SortableJS/Sortable).

   using the following command to install the Sortablejs.

   ```
   npm install sortablejs --save
   ```

   Then, check the node_modules folder to verify whether it contain this plugin.

   After that, open the angular.json file to add the js reference:

   ```
   "scripts": ["node_modules/sortablejs/Sortable.min.js"]
   ```

   Install [angular-sortablejs](https://github.com/SortableJS/angular-sortablejs)

   using the following command to install the angular-sortablejs:

   ```
   npm i sortablejs angular-sortablejs
   ```

   Then, in the app.module.ts file, import the SortablejsModule, code like this:

   ```
   import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
   import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
   import { SortablejsModule} from 'angular-sortablejs'
   import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

   @NgModule({
     declarations: [
       AppComponent
     ],
     imports: [
       BrowserModule,
       SortablejsModule
     ],
     providers: [],
     bootstrap: [AppComponent]
   })
   export class AppModule { }
   ```
2. using these plugin in angular components:

   app.component.ts:

   ```
   import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

   // import the sortablejs
   import * as Sortable from 'sortablejs'
   import { $ } from 'protractor';
   @Component({
   selector: 'app-root',
   templateUrl: './app.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
   })
   export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
   title = 'angular-sample';

   cities = [
       'Ankara',
       'Moscow',
       'Munich',
       'Paris',
       'Washington',
   ];

   ngOnInit (){

       var el = document.getElementById('items');
       var sortable = Sortable.create(el);
   }
   }
   ```

   app.component.html

   ```
   <!--The content below is only a placeholder and can be replaced.-->
   <div style="text-align:center">
   <h1>
       Welcome to {{ title }}!
   </h1>
   </div>

   <h2>using angular-sortablejs</h2>
   <ul class="nav nav-pills mb-3" [sortablejs]="cities">
   <li class="nav-item" *ngFor="let city of cities">
       <a class="nav-link active mr-1">{{ city }}</a>
   </li>
   </ul>

   <h2>using SortableJS/Sortable</h2>
   <ul id="items">
       <li>item 1</li>
       <li>item 2</li>
       <li>item 3</li>
   </ul>
   ```

The result like this:

[image]

And the polyfill file [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FbvTq.png).